# AWS CDK deploy in CodePipeline/CodeBuild

Tags: typescript, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy a AWS CDK app on AWS CodePipeline using CodeBuild actions.

The build and deploy works perfect locally (as it would!) but when running on CodeBuild, `cdk` command fails with

```
Cannot find module './index'
Subprocess exited with error 1
```

This is most likely something trivial but scratching my head trying to figure out what!

The project structure is auto-generated (with `cdk init --language typescript`)

```
<>/cdk$ ls
README.md  app  cdk.context.json  cdk.json  cdk.out  jest.config.js  lib  node_modules  package.json  test  tsconfig.json  yarn.lock
```

`buildspec.yml` for the `Build` stage is

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - cd ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/cdk
      - yarn install
      - yarn build
artifacts:
  base-directory: ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/cdk
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

`buildspec.yml` for the `Deploy` stage is (the input directory to this stage is the artifact from `Build` stage i.e. the `cdk` directory)

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install -g aws-cdk
      - cdk --version

  build:
    commands:
      - cd ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR} # this is cdk directory
      - cdk ls
      - cdk deploy app
```

The `Deploy` stage throws the `Cannot find module './index'` error at the `cdk ls` step. Since the above build/deploy steps work locally (in a clean checkout) I suspect it could be something to do with copying artifacts from `Build` to `Deploy` stages is what's causing the problem, but can't pinpoint what. Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

Comment: Try to add `ls` before `cdk ls` command to verify that all files are there

Comment: Yeah, tried and that and all the files seem to be there..

Comment: Weird.. can you share the steps you doing manually? I know it's the same as the buildspec.yaml but there might be some small changes that need to be made

Comment: Yes, this is indeed weird. May be I'm missing something simple.. 

The steps I run manually are `npm install && npm run build && cdk deploy`

Comment: Replicated with a minimal app https://github.com/IndikaUdagedara/CDKSample

Comment: Let's talk here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213543/buildspec-cdk

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with CodeBuild that it breaks all your symlinks when it creates your artifact => https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245780

The error `Cannot find module './index'` is because your `cdk.json` has a command to use `ts-node` and when cdk tries to run it from `node-modules/.bin/ts-node` the link is broken.

In order to do what you want, I suggest you to compress the code yourself on the build job. Something like:

```
      - yarn build
      - tar -czf /tmp/mycode.tar.gz .
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'mycode.tar.gz'
  discard-paths: true
  base-directory: '/tmp'
```

and decompress on the deploy job:

```
...
      - cd ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR} # this is cdk directory
      - tar -zxvf mycode.tar.gz
      - cdk ls
      - cdk deploy app
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolved it by passing in `enable-symlinks: yes` in my buildspec.yml

```yaml
artifacts:
  enable-symlinks: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Lambda code in cdk? Can you check the handler used and if it is present at that path, e.g.

```
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import * as path from 'path';

const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
  handler: 'dist/index.handler',  <======= Check index.js file is inside dist directory
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'lambda-handler')),
});
```